# Attempted import error: 'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' (imported as 'LeafletMap') HELP WHAT DO I DO

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";


function Map() {
    return (
        <div className='map'> 
            <LeafletMap>
                <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">
                    OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                />
            </LeafletMap>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Do you think you should use `MapContainer` instead of `Map`? Like `import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';`

Comment: if you are using the latest version of react-leaflet, the MapContainer is used instead of Map, see the setup page https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup